# LiveReload application VS Grunt built-in LiveReload?

Tags: gruntjs, reload, livereload, grunt-contrib-watch

I've recently started working on Grunt and figured out how to use its built-in live reload feature. I am using a WordPress theme to develop and asked the developers if they could better include the Grunt live reload functionality into the theme. They would insist on using the application instead (which isn't grunt). They said it would be dangerous to use as you should remember to remove the file from the production environment when you're done, even though I recommended a simple way to make sure it only stays in the development environment (which went ignored). I'm just curious as to what's the big disadvantage in using the grunt live reload vs the application? To me it seems better to keep it all with Grunt (by adding a couple of extra lines of code) instead of adding another tool to my workflow, granted it may be more dedicated to live reloading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work with `grunt-contrib-watch` with the livereload in almost every project and I didn't see any disantages so far.

The only problem that I can point out, is that livereload should be used only for lighter tasks or it can be a bit annoying if you're making him track heavy tasks.

It seems to me that your coworkers are being a skeptical for no reason, if you're not using grunt or gulp, putting them on your projects might be a huge improvement.